# R apply and filter is slow, alternatives?

Tags: r

I've written a function in apply to process a dataframe. I'm trying to go through, look at each combination of values in the columns "first" and "second", and make sure I don't already have a row like this ("second","first").  However, the function I wrote for this is taking a long time to run. I believe the problem is that I'm creating a subset of the data using dplyr's 'filter'. I'm fairly new to this work and not really sure how I can speed it up. Any suggestions would be great!

I'm running this on my personal computer that has 6GB of RAM and a 2.20GHz CPU. The dataframe is 6939380 obs of 7 variables. Here's a subset of my data.

```
first <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5")
second <- c("Q6","Q7","Q8","Q9","Q10")
third_Q <- c("Q11","Q12","Q13","Q14","Q15")
third_filter <- c("yes","yes","no","yes","maybe")
combo1 <- c("Q1_-_Q6","Q2_-_Q7","Q3_-_Q8","Q4_-_Q9","Q5_-_Q10")
combo2 <- c("Q6_-_Q1","Q7_-_Q2","Q8_-_Q3","Q9_-_Q4","Q10_-_Q5")
row <- c(1,2,3,4,5)


temp2 <- data.frame(first,second,third_Q,third_filter,combo1,combo2,row)
```

This is the function I wrote and am trying to run on this dataframe.

```
    fun3 <- function(x){
      #print the row # you are working on
      print(paste("row",as.numeric(x['row'],sep="_")))

      #get the row number you are looking for, the 3rd question, the 3rd filter, and the combo of questions you are asking
      rownum <- as.numeric(x['row'])
      q3 <- as.character(x['third_Q'])
      q3_filter <- as.character(x['third_filter'])
      combo <- as.character(x['combo1'])

      #subset the data to only look at rows that are above the row number you are analyzing, and the 3rd question & filter you are asking
      su <- (temp2 %>% filter(row<rownum & third_Q==q3 & third_filter==q3_filter))$combo2

      #compare the combo of the row you are working on to the 'combo2' for all of the rows in your subset
      result <- ifelse(combo %in% su,"discard","keep")

      return(result)
    }

    temp2$keep2 <- apply(temp2,1,fun3)
```

I'm using the "print....." part of the function to observe how fast my function is running. The output is fairly slow (it will print out a new row number every ~2 seconds). Given that I have 6,939,380 rows I would like to speed this up a bit.

Comment: Please provide a data sample and state a problem you want to solve with your function.

Comment: Would be useful to provide a dataset that gives you both 'keep' and 'discard' output to make it clear what you want to achieve. You could use a database join of temp2 onto itself with the further condition that the left table's row < right table's row.